# Link the Copyright attribute and image file with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, regex, image, beautifulsoup

I need to download and link the Copyright attribute and image file name. The problem is that img, together with src, is inside the `<wphimage>` tag, which has a 'Copyright' key in the date.

Using BeautifulSoup I managed to download 'Copyright' but how to link it with img?

code with html

```
<wphimage data="{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="Adela Frasineanu" data-lightview-caption="" class="lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG">
                    <img src="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" alt="John Smith">
                </a> 
               <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>
               <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" data-lightview-title="John Smith" data-lightview-caption="">+ </a>
    </span>
</wphimage>
```

code in py below

```
            soup = BeautifulSoup(row['Text'], features="html5lib")
            wphimages = soup.findAll('wphimage')

            for index, img in enumerate(wphimages):
                dict_as_str = img["data"].replace("'", '"')
                copyright_text.append((row["id"], json.loads(dict_as_str)['Copyright']))
```

**EDIT**

I get `{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}`

Here I have Copyrights - it is ok but I need name of file in `<img src`, from here: `<img src="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" alt="John Smith">`

Comment: What is the problem? Can you edit the question and post the expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely pls check

Comment: Are there more `<img>` tags inside `<wphimage>` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely No, but inside `row['Text']` sometimes is more then one `<wphimage>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, `.find()` method should be sufficient:

```
txt = '''<wphimage data="{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="Adela Frasineanu" data-lightview-caption="" class="lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG">
                    <img src="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" alt="John Smith">
                </a>
               <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>
               <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" data-lightview-title="John Smith" data-lightview-caption="">+ </a>
    </span>
</wphimage>


<wphimage data="{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'Something Different','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="Adela Frasineanu" data-lightview-caption="" class="lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG">
                    <img src="//example.com/static/images/other_image.JPG" alt="Something Different">
                </a>
               <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>
               <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" data-lightview-title="John Smith" data-lightview-caption="">+ </a>
    </span>
</wphimage>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for wphimage in soup.select('wphimage'):
    print(  json.loads(wphimage['data'].replace("'", '"'))['Copyright'], wphimage.find('img')['src'] )
```

Prints:

```
John Smith //example.com/static/images/image.JPG
Something Different //example.com/static/images/other_image.JPG
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working, but I got an error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` in this line: `json.loads(wphimage['data'].replace("'", '"'))['Copyright'], wphimage.find('img')['src']`

Comment: @webdev check if everything wphimage contains img tag. Seems it's not the case.